# Death in the days of Moshiach

Tags: death, messiah, resurrection-of-the-dead, messianic-redemption

I know the Rambam says nothing will change in the running of the world's nature.

See [Hilchos Melachim 12:1](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishneh_Torah,_Kings_and_Wars.12.1?with=all&lang=bi)

> אל יעלה על הלב שבימות המשיח יבטל דבר ממנהגו של עולם או יהיה שם חידוש במעשה בראשית אלא עולם כמנהגו נוהג
>
> Do not presume that in the Messianic age any facet of the world's nature will change or there will be innovations in the work of creation. Rather, the world will continue according to its pattern.

My question is as follows, does anyone argue on the Rambam and (as random examples of a different possible opinion) say that nobody will die any longer, will everyone be immortal, will the world transition to Gan Eden?

Comment: Rambam's most famous disputant, Rabad, argues in his animadversions right there.

Comment: See [Shaar Haggemul](http://www.daat.ac.il/daat/mahshevt/hagmul/6-4.htm)

Answer (score 1):

There are many who have alternate understandings of this subject including Ramban in Sefer HaGeulah, Rabbeinu Makir ben Abba Mori in Sefer Avkat Rochel and by extension Rashi and his school who bring Sefer Avkat Rochel in Machzor Vitry, and Rabbi Moshe Chaim Luzzato in Ma'amar HaGeulah to name just a few.

One of the keys to understanding Rambam's statement is to bear in mind what the true nature of the world was supposed to be prior to the sin of the tree of knowledge of good and evil.

Death and decay are not natural. They are a departure from the normal state of being in nature. Like Ramban explains to Bereshit 2:17.

> וסבת הויה והפסד ועל דעת רבותינו (עיין שבת נה) **אלמלא שחטא לא מת לעולם** כי הנשמה העליונית נותנת לו חיים לעד **והחפץ האלהי אשר בו בעת היצירה יהיה דבק בו תמיד והוא יקיים אותו לעד כמו שפירשתי** במלת וירא אלהים כי טוב (לעיל אחד) ודע כי **אין ההרכבה מורה על ההפסד אלא לדעת קטני אמנה** כי הבריאה היא בחיוב **אבל לדעת אנשי האמונה** האומרים **כי העולם מחודש בחפץ אלוהי פשוט גם הקיום יהיה בו לעד כל ימי החפץ וזה אמת ברור** אם כן **ביום אכלך ממנו מות תמות שאז תהיה בן מות לא תתקיים לעד בחפצי**

So what Rambam means is that the world, once repaired, will return to that normal, original state.

This is like is explained by Ramban to VaYikra 26:6 which says:

> דעת רבי שמעון שאמר משביתן שלא יזיקו (שם) יאמר והשבתי רעת החיות מן הארץ והוא הנכון **כי תהיה ארץ ישראל בעת קיום המצות כאשר היה העולם מתחילתו קודם חטאו של אדם הראשון** אין חיה ורמש ממית אדם וכמו שאמרו (ברכות לג) אין ערוד ממית אלא חטא ממית וזה שאמר הכתוב (ישעיהו יא ח) ושעשע יונק על חור פתן וכן ופרה ודוב תרענה ואריה כבקר יאכל תבן (שם פסוק ז) **כי לא היה הטרף בחיות הרעות רק מפני חטאו של אדם כי נגזר עליו להיות טרף לשניהם** והושם הטרף טבע להם גם לטרוף זו את זו כידוע כי בטרפם האדם פעם אחת יוסיפו להיות רעים יותר וכן אמר הכתוב (יחזקאל יט ג) וילמד לטרוף טרף אדם אכל והנה בבריאתו של עולם נאמר בחיות שנתן להם העשב לאכלה דכתיב (בראשית א ל) ולכל חית הארץ ולכל עוף השמים ולכל רומש על הארץ אשר בו נפש חיה את כל ירק עשב לאכלה ואמר הכתוב "ויהי כן" כי הוא הטבע אשר הושם בהם לעד **ואחר כך למדו הטרף מפני החטא הממית כאשר פירשתי** וכשהותר שחיטת בעלי החיים לבני נח אחרי המבול והזהיר על האדם (שם ט ה) ואך את דמכם לנפשותיכם אדרוש וגו' את נפש האדם ולא נפש חיה מיד חיה בחברתה נשארו על מנהגם לטרוף **ובהיות ארץ ישראל על השלמות תשבת רעת מנהגם ויעמדו על הטבע הראשון אשר הושם בהם בעת יצירתם** וכבר הזכרתי מזה בסדר תולדות נח (בראשית ט ו) **ועל כן אמר הכתוב על ימי הגואל היוצא מגזע ישי שישוב השלום בעולם** ויחדל הטרף ורעת הבהמה וכל הרמש כאשר היה בטבעם מתחילה והכוונה היתה בו על חזקיהו שביקש הקב"ה לעשותו משיח (סנהדרין צד) ולא עלתה זכותם לכך **ויהיה המעשה על המשיח העתיד לבא**

Comment: "Death and decay are not natural".  Thermodynamics 2nd Law - Entropy always increases. Disorder increases as time goes on - living cells and biological processes break down, resulting in decay and death.  They are indeed natural.

Comment: You say Ramban has an "alternate understandings of this subject" and then proceed to explain the words of the Rambam by appealing to Ramban's eschatological and/or metaphysical views. Do you not see why that is silly?

Comment: @DoubleAA No, the OP stated how he understands Rambam, meaning that what we see today is how the natural world behaved originally and it will stay that way. There are many who explain it the way the OP understands it. But as Ramban points out, that conclusion is incorrect. What the Torah describes as the sin of the tree of knowledge of good and evil distorted reality. Many things that we might call miraculous and a departure from nature are, in fact, the normal natural state of being.

Comment: @YaacovDeane You're just repeating yourself. Rambam say X; Ramban says Y. We get it. You're still inappropriately using one to explain the other. Rambam is explicit that predators will still hunt prey, unlike what Ramban claims is "natural". You can't pretend these two agree and expect to get away with it.

Comment: @Gary The laws of Thermodynamics are equilibrium equations. The effects change depending upon conditions. What you are focusing on and calling 'natural' are effects under one set of conditions. What I am describing as 'natural' or 'normal' are the effects displayed when the conditions are like they were at the beginning of creation. And that is what Ramban is describing. The conditions currently are not, in Ramban's words, in keeping with G-d's desire. (החפץ האלהי) The concept of moving toward 'entropy' is also relevant in regard to 'Olam HaBa' and is worth reflecting upon.

Comment: Entropy is the unavailability of energy for conversion into work. In other words, a state of rest, like Shabbat. And that too is how the Torah describes the world to come (עולם הבא), the time which is 'all Shabbat'.

Comment: @DoubleAA Actually, Rambam says that all those things he writes about on this subject won't be understood properly until they actually occur and he acknowledges that it may be different than how he portrays it.

Comment: @YaacovDeane Actually, I never denied that nor does it matter when it comes to describing his best prediction.