# Death After Resurrection?

Tags: olam-haba-world-to-come, resurrection-of-the-dead

This question is in reference to the question and answer given [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/rambam-on-olam-haba-mashiach-and-techiyat-hameitim?noredirect=1&lq=1)

**After the resurrection of the dead, will those who resurrected die again?**

If so:

**Why then do the dead resurrect?**

**And where or what is the *final* destination?**

I have had many assumptions of my own, based on prophecies of the rebuilding of the Third Temple, that the Temple would stand forever. Does forever not really mean forever then?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1:

> After the resurrection of the dead, will those who resurrected die again?

The Rishonim are divided on this question. According to the Rambam and Ibn Ezra those that merit resurrection will indeed die once again.

Rambam, [Treatise on Resurrection](https://www.daat.ac.il/daat/mahshevt/mekorot/thiyat-2.htm):

> אלו האנשים אשר ישובו נפשותם לגופות ההם, יאכלו וישתו וישגלו ויולידו
> וימותו אחרי חיים ארוכים מאוד כחיים הנמצאים בימות המשיח. ואמנם החיים
> שאין מוות אחריהם, הוא חיי העה"ב, אחר שאין גוף בהם. שאנחנו נאמין, והוא
> האמת אצל כל בן דעת, שהעה"ב נפשות מבלי גופות כמלאכים.
>
> Those
> individuals whose souls return to their bodies [after death] will eat
> and drink and engage in sexual intercourse and sire children and die
> after an extremely long life like the life which will exist during the
> days of the Messiah. Further, the life following which there is no
> death, is the life in the world to come because there are no
> [physical] bodies there. We firmly believe and this is the truth which
> every intelligent person accepts that in the world to come souls
> without bodies will exist like angels.

[Ibn Ezra, Daniel 12:2](https://www.sefaria.org/Ibn_Ezra_on_Daniel.12.2.1?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en):

> שהצדיקים שמתו בגלות יחיו בבוא הגואל כי עליהם כתוב כימי העץ ימי עמי
> ואז יתענגו בלויתן ובזיז ובבהמות וימותו פעם שניה ויחיו בתחית המתים
> בהיותם בעולם הבא, שאינם אוכלים ושותים רק נהנים מזיו שכינה
>
> The righteous who died in exile will be resurrected when the messiah
> comes, for to them apply the words, "the days of My people shall be as
> lng as the days of the tree." (Is. 65:22) They will delight themselves
> with Leviathan, Ziz, and Behemoth and die a second time, only to be
> resurrected again in the world-to-come, in which they will neighter
> eat nor drink but instead behold and enjoy the glory of the divine
> presence.

2:

> If so: Why then do the dead resurrect?

The Rambam doesn't really explore or speculate on the purpose of the resurrection, but emphasizes that belief in the occurrence of this wondrous miracle is a function of belief in the words of the prophets and Hazal.

3:

> And where or what is the final destination?

In the Maimonidean tradition, it is the immortal and non-corporeal life of the soul. It is this stage of existence which he refers to as 'Olam ha-Ba (the World to Come). You can find a description of his conception in [Ch. 8 of Hilkhoth Teshubhah](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishneh_Torah%2C_Repentance.8.1?lang=bi).

The Ramban (in [Sha'ar ha-Gemul](https://www.sefaria.org/Sha%27ar_Ha%27Gemul_of_the_Ramban.45?lang=bi)) disagreed with all of this and held that after one dies, the soul goes to Gan Eden and upon resurrection the soul is reunited with the body, which is then in a purified state and goes on to live eternally. It is this last stage which he refers to as 'Olam ha-Ba.

Answer (score 2):

See Derech Hashem 1:3 and 2:2, Maamar HaIkkarim Ch. 8

The **first general resurrection**, in the days of Moshiach, is in order to bring every single person who ever lived back to be judged, along with their whole nation.

Then, most people will die again by the Jewish year of 6000, because this world needs to undergo a change in order to prepare it to be "Olam Haba". Some particularly righteous people will stay and grow wings and fly above the world as it undergoes this change (through a mabul, see [Sanhedrin 92b](https://www.sefaria.org/Sanhedrin.92b.1)).

Then after 1000 years, the world will have become Olam Haba, and there will be a **final resurrection** for all those that merit it.

I believe this opinion that the Ramchal brings is based on the Arizal, who said this is the correct opinion of the many opinions on this matter, and much of the Ashkenazi, Sefardi and Chassidic orthodox communities have accepted his opinion.

Comment: The 1st stage of resurrection is for the “select individuals” (יחידי סגולה) at the beginning of the Days of Moshiach. This is the subject of Sukkah 52b, Yoma 5a and elsewhere. In the language of Rambam in Mishneh Torah, it is when the individual presumed to be Moshiach transitions to Moshiach with certainty. The 2nd general resurrection pertains to the great & awesome day of judgment referred to in Joel 3:4 & Malachi 3:23. Like the Rebbe explains, this is judgment of the nations. Not Jews. Those judged in merit receive their reward in the world of souls. See Yesodei HaTorah to understand.

Comment: Related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/90990/7303

Comment: And also: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/85236/7303

Comment: I have made an edit that should allow for the opinion you brought, thanks as always

Comment: And also: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/82281/7303

Comment: And also: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/61459/7303